# XML cached in local testing

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, caching, loading

My question is about XML loading. I need to avoid xml caching.

On a web server, the technique is adding a  random param to reload each time the XML file.
But on local testing (in Flash CS4 IDE, CTRL + Enter), the following lines are not possible :

```
var my_date : Date;
path = "toto.xml?time="+my_date.getSeconds()+my_date.getMilliseconds();
```

Is there any trick to bypass this issue ?
I've read on different forum about the "delete" method, we delete the xml object and then recreate one new.

In my case, I put : `myXML = null; myXML = new XML ( loadedData );`
But it doesn't work at all.

I found something interesting but for Air 1.0 unfortunately with the `cacheResponse`.
In AS3 I found :

```
var loader     : URLLoader  = new URLLoader();
var urlRequest : URLRequest = new URLRequest( xmlUrl );
var header     : URLRequestHeader = new URLRequestHeader ( "pragma", "no-cache" );
urlRequest.requestHeaders.push(header);
```

But it doesn't work.

I spent many hours on that problem, if anyone has a good solution...
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Recently I've started using a debug proxy that let's me disable caching altogether, but before I did that I used this little actionscript snippet to deal with this issue:

```
import flash.system.Capabilities;

var url:String = "foo.xml";
if (Capabilities.playerType == "StandAlone" || Capabilities.playerType == "External") {
    // running locally, cache busting not required
} else {
    // running in browser
    url += "?rnd=" + Math.random();
}
```

Comment: It should be selected as answer. It sure helped me.

Answer (score 0):

Major troll, but: Pragma isn't the best option for controlling cache. Take some time to study caching: http://www.mnot.net/cache_docs/#PRAGMA

And after all that, adding a random number to the end of the URL querystring is still a surefire way of get past all that monkeybusiness with caching.